# Triplet Deep Learning Embedding Loss Functions

Tags: neural-networks, conv-neural-network, triplet-loss

Triplet embeddings consist of mapping a group of images to an embedding space, such that images deemed more similar to each other end up closer together. The "triplet" comes from training, where we have (A,P,N), where A is our anchor image, P is a positive example image (one deemed similar to A), and N is a negative example.

So the architecture is as follows: each element of the triplet is first mapped through a convolutional neural net, followed by an embedding net. We denote this with function $f$, so that for image $x$, $f(x)$ is the embedding.

My question concerns the choice of loss function. As an example here are two different approaches:

[FaceNet: A Unified Embedding for Face Recognition and Clustering](https://arxiv.org/abs/1503.03832)

[Deep metric learning using Triplet network](https://arxiv.org/abs/1412.6622)

In the first approach, separation of positive/negative examples is achieved using a margin of separation:

$$\left[\left\|f(x_i^A)-f(x_i^P)\|_2^2-\|f(x_i^A)-f(x_i^N)\right\|_2^2+\alpha\right]_+.$$

The second approach is to use a softmax loss:

$$\frac{\exp(\|f(x_i^a)-f(x_i^p)\|_2)}{\exp(\|f(x_i^a)-f(x_i^p)\|_2)+\exp(\|f(x_i^a)-f(x_i^n)\|_2)},$$

which has the property that as the loss goes to 0, $\frac{\|f(x_i^a)-f(x_i^p)\|_2}{\|f(x_i^a)-f(x_i^n)\|_2}\rightarrow 0$, which achieves the desire to embed positive examples closer than negative examples.

I'm sure there are other ways, and I'm curious if there's a nice review of which methods work better?